# About the query limit of big query

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to raise the upper limit number of BigQuery query jobs currently being used.
The default is about 50, so I would like you to give about 200 by hope, is it possible?

Comment: Have you tried to contact support for that product?

Answer (score 1):

Per BiqQuery [official](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas) page the only way to do this is to contact their support/sale team

**Point 1**

> Concurrent rate limit for on-demand, interactive queries — 50 concurrent queries
>
> Queries with results that are returned from the query cache, and dry run queries do not count against this limit. You can specify a dry run query using the --dry_run flag or by setting the dryRun property in a query job.
>
> This limit is applied at the project level. **To raise the limit, contact support or contact sales**.

Nevertheless, note that this limit is for `interactive` queries if you are willing to let BigQuery allocate the queries for you use `batch` queries

**Point 2**

> Batch queries don't count towards your concurrent rate limit, which can make it easier to start many queries at once.

**Point 3**

> BigQuery queues each batch query on your behalf, and starts the query as soon as idle resources are available,

See the offical [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/running-queries) for more details